# LSTM state-of-art

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

Can you advice me a good paper which talks about the LSTM's state-of-art? 
I have already searched on google but I have not found anything interesting
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the paper "[LSTM: A Search Space Odyssey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04069)" by Klaus Greff, Rupesh Kumar Srivastava, Jan Koutník, Bas R. Steunebrink, Jürgen Schmidhuber.

It is not a super new paper (it's from 2015), but it compares 8 variants of LSTMs on 3 tasks (speech recognition, handwriting recognition, and polyphonic music modeling), and the authors conclude that none of the analysed variants can significantly outperform the standard LSTM architecture.